# write utf-8 content in files / python 3

Tags: python-3.x, file, utf-8

Its again about utf-8 issues, for the 1001st time. Please don't mark this question as duplicate, 'cause I cannot find answers elsewhere.

Since some months I am working successfully with the following small script (which may improved, I know that), which delivers me a simple database functionality. But I wrote it for very simple data storage, like local config and auth data, let's say not for more sophisticated content as known from cookies. It worked for me, until I tried to store non latin characters for the 1st time.

In the following script I already added the `import codecs` stuff, including the altered lines `f = codecs.open(file, 'w', 'utf-8')`. Do not know if this is the right approach.

Can somebody show me the trick ? Let's say "John Doe" is french, "John Doé", how do I store it ?

The class itself (to be imported)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, errno
import json
import codecs

class Ddpos:

    def db(self,table,id,col=''):
        table = '/Users/michag/Documents/ddposdb/'+table

        try:
            os.makedirs(table)
            os.chmod(table, 0o755)
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise

        file = table+'/'+id+'.txt'

        if not os.path.isfile(file):
            f = codecs.open(file, 'w', 'utf-8')
            f.write('{}')
            f.close()

        f = codecs.open(file, 'r', 'utf-8')
        r = json.loads(f.readline().strip())
        f.close()

        if isinstance(col, str) and len(col) > 0:
            if col in r:
                return json.dumps(r[col])
            else:
                return ''

        elif isinstance(col, list) and len(col) > 0:
            res = {}
            for el in range(0,len(col)):
                if col[el] in r:
                    res[col[el]] = r[col[el]]
            return json.dumps(res)

        elif isinstance(col, dict) and len(col) > 0:
            for el in col:
                r[el] = col[el]
            f = codecs.open(file, 'w', 'utf-8')
            f.write(json.dumps(r))
            f.close()
            return json.dumps(r)

        else:
            return json.dumps(r)

ddpos = Ddpos()
```

The call / usage

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from ddpos import *

# set values and return all values as dict
print ('1.: '+ddpos.db('cfg','local',{'admin':'John Doé','email':'johndoe@email.com'}))

# return all values as dict
print ('2.: '+ddpos.db('cfg','local'))

# return one value as string
print ('3.: '+ddpos.db('cfg','local','email'))

# return two or more values as dict
print ('4.: '+ddpos.db('cfg','local',['admin','email']))
```

It prints and stores this in case of "John Doe"

```
1.: {"admin": "John Doe", "email": "johndoe@email.com"}
2.: {"admin": "John Doe", "email": "johndoe@email.com"}
3.: "johndoe@email.com"
4.: {"admin": "John Doe", "email": "johndoe@email.com"}
```

and this in case of french guy "John Doé"

```
1.: {"email": "johndoe@email.com", "admin": "John Do\u00e9"}
2.: {"email": "johndoe@email.com", "admin": "John Do\u00e9"}
3.: "johndoe@email.com"
4.: {"email": "johndoe@email.com", "admin": "John Do\u00e9"}
```

For me it is more important to learn and to understand, how it works and why or why not, but to know that there already classes which would do the job for me. Thanks for your support.

Comment: *"'cause I cannot find answers elsewhere"* isn't really a reason not to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Apart from that... What's wrong? The output looks 100% correct to me.

Comment: @Tomalak OK, let's say the output works as expected >for you :-)< and I do store it as `"admin": "John Do\u00e9"`, how do I use this later ?

Comment: So each of your "tables" is a file containing the json dump of a dict. But when you retrieve a value, you read that dict, parse it, extract the value you want, dump that to json again and return that. So you're going dict -> json -> dict -> json. You never get back a dict again, you always get a string. I think it would make more sense if you drop the `json.dumps()` wherever you have `return json.dumps(...)`

Comment: @mata Yes you're right. I dropped it except in `f.write(json.dumps(r))` and it works. It is stored still as `John Do\u00e9` but the output of `return` which is directly what `read` delivers, is correct: `2.: {'email': 'johndoe@email.com', 'admin': 'John Doé'}` . Thumbs up, thanks and 1+ from ddlab

Comment: only in the usage with `print` I needed to convert the result into string: `print ('2.: '+str(ddpos.db('cfg','local')))`

Comment: Don't add "SOLVED" to the title; post an answer and accept it.

Comment: @mata Btw. Now I believe that python3 deals with utf-8 itself, as I dropped the `codecs` things for testing, and it still works :-)

Comment: @deceze Do you mean I should answer my own question and include the corrected script ? But the laurels should be for user mata, not for me. Hmm.

Comment: Well, *somebody* post an answer, I don’t care who. ;)

Comment: @mata Thanks again, this what you wrote, or the kind how you did it, is the way I like, to teach sth. to smb. by including his own brain, instead of just write down the correct code, which again may be hard to understand. Btw. the data structure is slightly different: Table is the containing directory, wich may be sub- or subsubdir like `ddpos.db('what/ever/folder/structure','filename')`. The file is represented by the so called `id`

Comment: Omitting the `encoding` from `open()` is not a good idea because then the used encoding is platform dependent, so it's better to always include it. In this case it won't make much difference because `json.dumps()` per default has `ensure_ascii=True`, so actually only produces ascii with non-ascii characters escaped. If that wasn't the case, then you would get errors when trying to copy your files to a different platform (errors when trying to open files as utf-8 which are not, or strage characters when opening utf-8 files with some other encoding).

Comment: @mata OK, I understand. Currently I cannot test it on other platforms. So what would you suggest: `f = open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8')` or (with `import codecs`) `f = codes.open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8')` ?

Comment: Like I said, you're acutally only getting ascii strings, so it doesn't really matter in this special case, but generally I'm all for explicitly specifying the input/output encodigs of files. Imho `open()` using the platform locale by default in text mode was a big mistake, should have used utf8 from the beginning, but any explicit locale, even ascii, would have been better. The [upcoming utf-8 mode](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0540/) is a step in the right direction. But in the end your actual problem doesn't really have anything to do with encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I made some improvements. Now the stored dict is human readable (for those unbelievers, like me) and sorted case insensitive. This sorting process for sure consumes a bit of performance, but hey, I will use the read-only process some houndred times more than the write process.

Now the stored dict looks like this:

```
{
        "auth_descr": "dev unit, office2",
        "auth_email": "me@myemail.com",
        "auth_key": "550e3 **shortened sha256** d73b1",
        "auth_unit_id": "2.3.1",
        "vier": "44é", # utf-8 example
        "Vjier": "vier44" # uppercase example
}
```

I don't know where I did a mistake in earlier version(s), but if you take a look on the utf-8 example. "é" now is stored as an "é" and not as "\u00e9".

The class now looks like this (with minor changes)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, errno
import json

class Ddpos:

        def db(self,table,id,col=''):
                table = '/ddpos/db/'+table

                try:
                        os.makedirs(table)
                        os.chmod(table, 0o755)
                except OSError as e:
                        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                                raise

                file = table+'/'+id+'.txt'

                if not os.path.isfile(file):
                        f = open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
                        f.write('{}')
                        f.close()

                f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
                r = json.loads(f.read().strip())
                f.close()

                if isinstance(col, str) and len(col) > 0:
                        if col in r:
                                return r[col]
                        else:
                                return ''

                elif isinstance(col, list) and len(col) > 0:
                        res = {}
                        for el in range(0,len(col)):
                                if col[el] in r:
                                        res[col[el]] = r[col[el]]
                        return res

                elif isinstance(col, dict) and len(col) > 0:
                        for el in col:
                                r[el] = col[el]
                        w = '{\n'
                        for key in sorted(r, key=lambda y: y.lower()):
                                w += '\t"%s": "%s",\n' % (key, r[key])
                        w = w[:-2]+'\n'
                        w += '}'
                        f = open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
                        f.write(w)
                        f.close()
                        return r

                else:
                        return r

ddpos = Ddpos()
```

Answer (score 1):

After moderator deceze I answer my own question, with credentials to user mata and python3 itself.

Here's the "new" script. The poor french guy now is renamed to "J€hn Doéß" and he's still alive.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, errno
import json

class Ddpos:

    def db(self,table,id,col=''):
        table = '/Users/michag/Documents/ddposdb/'+table

        try:
            os.makedirs(table)
            os.chmod(table, 0o755)
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise

        file = table+'/'+id+'.txt'

        if not os.path.isfile(file):
            f = open(file, 'w')
            f.write('{}')
            f.close()

        f = open(file, 'r')
        r = json.loads(f.readline().strip())
        f.close()

        if isinstance(col, str) and len(col) > 0:
            if col in r:
                return r[col]
            else:
                return ''

        elif isinstance(col, list) and len(col) > 0:
            res = {}
            for el in range(0,len(col)):
                if col[el] in r:
                    res[col[el]] = r[col[el]]
            return res

        elif isinstance(col, dict) and len(col) > 0:
            for el in col:
                r[el] = col[el]
            f = open(file, 'w')
            f.write(json.dumps(r))
            f.close()
            return r

        else:
            return r

ddpos = Ddpos()
```